# Google Contacts API query for n popular contacts

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

is there are way to query only n popular contacts ?
for example something like:

```
http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=50&popular=true
```

that will return only the 50 popular contacts.
(like in gmail contacts there is 20 popular contacts).

if there is isn't a way to query that, is there a way to check which of all contacts sre most popular.
popular= more email activity with them then with others.

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have struggled with this for quite sometime. Internet research suggests that this was removed from the API a few years ago, mostly since the "Most Contacted" section of the Google Contacts is inaccurate.
To perform the task of fetching the "most contacted" I'm requesting the user for readonly mail permission, and am actively reading the last 3 months email headers. This produces the same results, but with a huge privacy penalty. I wish google would've supported this natively.

Comment: So you mean you have to do one request per contact just to know the interaction level you have with this contact? That's a lot more requests also :( but could work