# Frequently contacted contacts in Google Contacts API

Tags: google-contacts-api

I'm trying to get the frequently contacted contacts from 
Google Contacts API version 3.0.

I have checked the Google documentation https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ that there is no option provided for getting frequently contacted contacts.

Is this API providing the data for frequently contacted contacts or not? Please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Contacts API query for n popular contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601791/google-contacts-api-query-for-n-popular-contacts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I cannot also find related documentations regarding your case. I have found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24606907/5832311) which stated that the "Most Contacted" section of the Google Contacts is inaccurate.

> To perform the task of fetching the "most contacted" I'm requesting the user for readonly mail permission, and am actively reading the last 3 months email headers. This produces the same results, but with a huge privacy penalty. I wish google would've supported this natively.

You may, however, file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191607&template=824105) for this.

Comment: Feature request entered, please upvote https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79731139